# Postgres stacked diagnostics - print declared variable where error occurs from select into

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find the value of a field where a particular exception occurs in a select query:

```
SQLSTATE : 22008 - 
   date/time field value out of range: "09/10/2017"
```

I can see the problem is with the date format, but I want to find the 'ocid' (our company terminology for the document id) of the record where this occurs so I can report this back to fix manually.

My attempt to find this problem row is so far using a DO statement, and declaring the `ocid` as the `rec` variable:

```
do
$$
declare
    rec record;
    v_state   TEXT;
    v_msg     TEXT;
    v_detail  TEXT;
    v_hint    TEXT;
    v_context TEXT;
begin
    with cte as (
    [...] # some cte declarations
    )
        SELECT
                cte.ocid into rec
                FROM cte
                where cte.date < timestamp '2018-01-01';
                
       exception when others then

            get stacked diagnostics
                v_state   = returned_sqlstate,
                v_msg     = message_text,
                v_detail  = pg_exception_detail,
                v_hint    = pg_exception_hint,
                v_context = pg_exception_context;

            raise notice E'Got exception:
                state  : %
                message: %
                detail : %
                hint   : %
                context: %', v_state, v_msg, v_detail, v_hint, v_context;

            raise notice E'Got exception:
                SQLSTATE: %
                SQLERRM: %', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;

            raise notice '%', rec;

end; $$;
```

But nothing is returned in the results.

When I remove `into rec` - I get the stacked diagnostics as expected:

```
 ...
 [2021-09-08 12:38:52] [00000] Got exception: [2021-09-08 12:38:52]
 SQLSTATE: 22008 [2021-09-08 12:38:52] SQLERRM: date/time field value
 out of range: "09/10/2017"
 ...
```

But I'd like to add to this the value of the 'ocid' field too.

I'm new to exception catching so any explanations greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the statement fails, `rec` is not assigned to.

You'll have to split up the operation, for example by inserting the values of the CTE into a temporary table.

Better options may exist, depending on what you do inside the CTE.